# Major mutation framework 0 mutants covered

Tags: testing, mutation, mutation-testing

When I run the major tool (http://mutation-testing.org/) on the examples provided, I am able to generate and analyze mutants.

I am also able to generate mutants from my own .java files but when I try to run my junit test suites on them, it reports 0 mutants covered.

Could anyone tell me why this might be the case?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible reasons, based on how Major works:

1. The generated mutants are overwritten by another compilation step between mutant generation and test execution.
2. The mutants are not enabled during test execution. By default, the generated and embedded mutants have no effect as they are guarded by a condition in the program code.

Could you please provide a minimal working example? This should allow us to determine which of the two issues it is.